# Open an expanding view by dragging or tapping

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingdrawer

I am trying to implement something similar to a notification like expanding view, something close to Android's Sliding Drawer. I am planning to put a recycler view in the place of the calendar and be able to drag it or tap on the arrow to reveal the RecyclerView Does anyone know how? (The image below explain what I want to achieve).

someting like [this](http://techqa.info/programming/question/22403320/android-drag-and-expand-view) will do help. SlidingDrawer is deprecated. I am not sure I could it with that event it wasn't

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this
[Sliding Up Panel Library](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)

I am using it in my current project and I have no problems..